# Time Complexity of Python TicTacToe function

Tags: python, time-complexity, tic-tac-toe

```
def TicTacToe():
    board = [['S' for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
    BoardState(board)

    for i in range(8):
        if(i % 2 == 0):
            print("Enter the position player 1: ")
            a = int(input())
            b = int(input())
            if(board[a - 1][b - 1] == 'S'):
                board[a - 1][b - 1] = 1
            else:
                print("Invalid Input, game over")
                return
        else:
            print("Enter the position player 2: ")
            a = int(input())
            b = int(input())
            if(board[a - 1][b - 1] == 'S'):
                board[a - 1][b - 1] = 0
            else:
                print("Invalid input, game over")
                return
                
        BoardState(board)
        
        if(board[0][0] == 1 and board[1][1] == 1 and board[2][2] == 1):
            return "Player 1 wins"
        if(board[0][0] == 0 and board[1][1] == 0 and board[2][2] == 0):
            return "Player 2 wins"
        if(board[0][2] == 1 and board[1][1] == 1 and board[2][0] == 1):
            return "Player 1 wins"
        if(board[0][2] == 0 and board[1][1] == 0 and board[2][0] == 0):
            return "Player 2 wins"
        if(CheckState(board) == 0):
            return "game over"
        
    return "Draw"

def CheckState(board):        
    for x in range(3):
        if board[x][0] == board[x][1] == board[x][2] != 'S' \
        or board[0][x] == board[1][x] == board[2][x] != 'S':
            return 0
        
def BoardState(board):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(board[i][j], end = ' ')
        print("\n")    


TicTacToe();
```

This is a not-so-clean code I wrote for the game of tictactoe. What would be its time complexity?

The program consists of 3 functions and I wish to calculate the complexity for the same. Would it be O(1) as the input size is already fixed it doesn't vary with whatever the user inputs?

Comment: If your main loop waits for input, then the bottleneck really is the waiting time for the user's input. How would you imagine applying "time complexity" to that? Time complexity is about a computational algorithm that has varying input, not about a loop where you wait in each iteration for the user's input.

Comment: oh I see. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Also: Your question was about the `TicTacToe` function, but it takes no input itself, so also from that perspective it makes no sense to speak of time complexity. Time complexity is only meaningful when there is a variable part in the input the function under consideration is given. This should be a parameter to the function (not the function asking for user input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be O(1) as the input size is already fixed it doesn't vary with whatever the user inputs?

Yes, that is exactly right. All of the loops have a fixed number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're actually talking about two different problems:   The first is a program to act as a "referee", similar to your program above.  The second is a program to play against a human player (or other program).

For complexity, think about the case of an N x N tic tac toe board.  In that case, I *think* the complexity of the first problem is O(N), while for the second, it's exponential in N.

Comment: But if N = 3 (for a 3 x 3 board) it would be constant time right?